# How to set Object Value equals Object value inside variable

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a variable set to an object:

```
var myConfig = {
  elementID: "Test",
  cookieName: "myTest",
  cookieExpiresAfterDays: 1,
  cookieDomain: ".localhost:3000/",
  privacyPolicy: "",

  services: [
    {
      name: "GoogleAnalytics",
      default: !0,
      required: !0,
      onlyOnce: !0,
    },
  ],

  translations: {
    GoogleAnalytics: {
      description: `<p>CookieDomain: ${cookieDomain}</p>`,
      title: "Google Analytics",
    },
  }
};
```

In this block:

```
 translations: {
    GoogleAnalytics: {
      description: `<p>CookieDomain: ${cookieDomain}</p>`,
      title: "Google Analytics",
    },
  }
```

I need to set `cookieDomain: cookieDomain` but it returns me an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: cookieDomain is not defined

and when I try `cookieDomain: this.cookieDomain` it prints undefined.

How can I access the correct value?

Comment: The compiler can't find a definition of `cookieDomain` in this context. Be sure you've defined in your module or earlier in the containing function. Perhaps update your question to include the point where `cookieDomain` is defined if you're still having trouble.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @MykWillis, that is the problem this is a config script that loads like that, there is no function or anything else, that's why I need to access the value inside of object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have two solutions here either

1. define the `cookieDomain` variable in the same file before the initializing `myConfig` object
2. pass the `cookieDomain` value as a parameter so the `myConfig` object would be

```
var myConfig = {
  elementID: "Test",
  cookieName: "myTest",
  cookieExpiresAfterDays: 1,
  cookieDomain: ".localhost:3000/",
  privacyPolicy: "",

  services: [
    {
      name: "GoogleAnalytics",
      default: !0,
      required: !0,
      onlyOnce: !0,
    },
  ],

  translations: ({cookieDomain}) => {
    GoogleAnalytics: {
      description: `<p>CookieDomain: ${cookieDomain}</p>`,
      title: "Google Analytics",
    },
  }
};
```

and then you need to call the `translations` block by

```
myConfig.translations({cookieDomain: 'some value here'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a getter in this case, that reads from the `myConfig` variable:

```
var myConfig = {
  elementID: "Test",
  cookieName: "myTest",
  cookieExpiresAfterDays: 1,
  cookieDomain: ".localhost:3000/",
  privacyPolicy: "",

  services: [
    {
      name: "GoogleAnalytics",
      default: !0,
      required: !0,
      onlyOnce: !0,
    },
  ],

  translations: {
    GoogleAnalytics: {
      get description(){
        return `<p>CookieDomain: ${myConfig.cookieDomain}</p>`
      },
      title: "Google Analytics",
    },
  }
};
```

If the value of `myConfig` may change, you can use nested lazy getters:

```
var myConfig = {
  elementID: "Test",
  cookieName: "myTest",
  cookieExpiresAfterDays: 1,
  cookieDomain: ".localhost:3000/",
  privacyPolicy: "",

  services: [
    {
      name: "GoogleAnalytics",
      default: !0,
      required: !0,
      onlyOnce: !0,
    },
  ],

  //We must use a getter here, so the outer object is available through `this`
  get translations() {
    delete this.translations
    const outerObj = this
    return this.translations = {
      GoogleAnalytics: {
        get description(){
          return `<p>CookieDomain: ${outerObj.cookieDomain}</p>`
        },
        title: "Google Analytics",
      },
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment @FZs! Both solutions worked! But in sake for simplicity I'll just declare the variable before `myConfig`. Thank you very much!